# How can I auto-import contacts from PayPal into Highrise?

Tags: crm

PayPal collects my customers' addresses, but I need an easy way to integrate them into my CRM.

Comment: Which CRM are you using?  Can you tell us if the CRM has a REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old answer here, but try using this [PayPal to Highrise Zap](https://zapier.com/z/Cfa/zapbook/paypal/highrise/120/add-paypal-customers-highrise/).

It'll let you create contacts in Highrise or add notes to existing contacts when they buy something from you in PayPal.

Disclosure: I run Zapier, but this is what I'd use even if I didn't. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to get a CSV of your contacts to import them into Highrise:

http://help.37signals.com/highrise/questions/441-how-do-i-add-a-group-of-contacts-to-highrise-can-i-import-a-file-with-my-contact-info

It appears that paypal supports CSV export:

http://www.clovercitysells.com/ebook/csv-export.pdf

which has step-by-step instructions on how to export the details.